# Javascript key press to make div larger

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am making a mini game for a school project and I need help with this piece of code. I want:

By pressing a key on the keyboard, the div with a image will be enlarged to a maximum size of 300px width and height.

After 30 seconds, if the size isn't reached, then give the user feedback to try again.

Everything I tried didn't work and I am new to JavaScript.

Here is my code:

---

```
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  if (evt.keyCode == 71) {
        var box = document.getElementById("water2");
            box.style.width="200px";
            box.style.height= "300px";
  } else if (evt.keyCode == 191) {
        var box = document.getElementById("water1");
            box.style.width="200px";
            box.style.height= "300px";
  }
};
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="water1"></div>
<div id="water2"></div>
<div id="water3"></div>
<div id="water4"></div>
<div id="water5"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    border: aqua 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: auto;

}



#water1{
    height: 1px;
    width: 3px;
    border: black;  
    float: left;
    background:url(img/animated-water-moving-blue-flowing.gif);
    float: right;

}
#water2{
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
    width: 3px;
    border: black;  
    background:url(img/animated-water-moving-blue-flowing.gif);

}
```

Comment: Add your HTML and CSS also, it does make a difference...

Comment: I did! i hope you can help!

Comment: You need to use units in values for style properties, like so: `box.style.width="200px";`

Comment: Please fix your CSS, you only need to specify the float property once per rule.

Comment: i did it now @MarcAudet

Comment: I have fix my CSS@MarcAudet

Comment: Ehh... Do you see `px` after `200` in my comment. That `px` is an CSS unit, it is oblique when setting properties which have some measures. Btw. you still have `float: left` and `float: right` in the same rule in your CSS.

Comment: ooh i See but i tried that but I do not what i want in my browser 
I want When you press a key like R once.. you see the div for 10% when you press again the R than you see 20% and so on till the 100% of the image size. @Teemu

Comment: First problem - you are overwriting your onkeydown handler.  Either use `addEventListener` or, better yet, combine the logic into a single onkeydown handler.

Comment: Then use `%` instead of `px` as unit. You would need a counter for the percent, then increase the counter by ten on each key hit. Notice also what dc5 and friedrich have said.

Comment: You changed the code that my answer referred to. That isn't that nice as nobody browsing this question will understand the initial problem and what all these people (including me) were talking about. In Addition, try to be more concrete about the occuring errors .. StackOverflow won't write your program ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, yes i am new here

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is rather simple:
The Event isn't captured properly because the upper layers seem to block it.

The following command ensures that the document captures your event.

```
document.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
```

Better you inform yourself about global event on this site:
http://javascript.about.com/library/bltut33.htm
By the way: I think the event you meant was document.onkeyup or document.onkeypress as it reacts only once.

After that, your code will need an urgent modification:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
if (evt.keyCode == 191) {
    var box = document.getElementById("water1");
    box.style.width="200";
    box.style.height= "300";
}
 };
```

will be overridden by this function:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
if (evt.keyCode == 71) {
    var box = document.getElementById("water2");
    box.style.width="200";
    box.style.height= "300";
}
 };
```

So merge them:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  if (evt.keyCode == 71) {
    var box = document.getElementById("water2");
    box.style.width="200";
    box.style.height= "300";
  } else if (evt.keyCode == 191) {
    var box = document.getElementById("water1");
    box.style.width="200";
    box.style.height= "300";
  }
};
```

To start a function after some seconds, use setTimeout:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

To read and set the properties of html-objects easily, get yourself familiar with JQuery:
http://jquery.com/

Have fun with your school project!

Comment: Thank you it works! But I want that when you press the key once you see 10% of the div and if you press again  + 10% till the 100%.

Comment: Then, set a counter at the `window` scope, increment it within the if clausule and use it to set the box's height.

Hell, I'd love to put _actual_ codes in comments.

Comment: Or consider reading the box-height, checking its length and then increasing it.

Comment: Well I am a beginner in this haha, now I merge my code. And where can i put the counter?

Comment: Don't merge the code in a question or all answer referring to that get useless. Consider a little tutorial like [link](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3) that will explain some basics. If you get errors, ask.